# How to add specific containers to PDF with PDFBox

Tags: java, spring, pdf, pdfbox, watermark

So I want to watermark a whole bunch of unformatted pdfs. The problem is that every pdf is different and sometimes the watermark can overlap the content. So I would like to create a new container pdf with margin and two boxes defined, first one for the watermark and the second one for the pdf original file without cropping any of its content, only scaling it. The result must be something like this:

[image]

What I am doing now is just to insert this logo in the original pdf page but as I said before it hides the content. I'm not interested in changing the transparency of the watermark.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve that containerization? What stopped you?

Comment: yes the containerization, the problem is scaling the pdfs to be in the content, and creating the containers on the main pdf. I have not found any tutorial online about this.